# Concatenate command string in a shell script

Tags: bash, shell, scripting

I am maintaining an existing shell script which assigns a command to a variable in side a shell script like:

```
MY_COMMAND="/bin/command -dosomething"
```

and then later on down the line it passes an "argument" to $MY_COMMAND by doing this :

```
MY_ARGUMENT="fubar"

$MY_COMMAND $MY_ARGUMENT
```

The idea being that `$MY_COMMAND` is supposed to execute with `$MY_ARGUMENT` appended.

Now, I am not an expert in shell scripts, but from what I can tell, `$MY_COMMAND` does not execute with `$MY_ARGUMENT` as an argument. However, if I do:

```
MY_ARGUMENT="itworks"
MY_COMMAND="/bin/command -dosomething $MY_ARGUMENT"
```

It works just fine.

Is it valid syntax to call `$MY_COMMAND $MY_ARGUMENT` so it executes a shell command inside a shell script with `MY_ARGUMENT` as the argument?

Comment: [I'm trying to put a command in a variable, but the complex cases always fail!](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050)

Comment: When you say, *...but from what I can tell, $MY_COMMAND does not execute with $MY_ARGUMENT as an argument.*, are you speculating or did you run a test that fails? It (`$MY_COMMAND $MY_ARGUMENT`) actually should work depending upon your context.

Comment: @mbratch: Yes, I ran it and it did not work as $MY_COMMAND $MY_ARGUMENT, basically the command didn't execute. I suppose I could redirect STDERR to STDOUT and catch the logs.

Comment: I did a simple test using that technique and it worked. For example, at the shell prompt, if I set `FOO=ls` and `BAR="*.c"`, then entering `$FOO $BAR` lists the `.c` files in my current directory. So you will need to share the context in which it's being used which is causing it to fail.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It works just the way you expect it to work, but `fubar` is going to be the second argument ( `$2` ) and not `$1`.
So if you `echo` arguments in your `/bin/command` you will get something like this:

```
echo "$1" # prints '-dosomething'
echo "$2" # prints 'fubar'
```

Answer (score 5):

With Bash you could use arrays:

```
MY_COMMAND=("/bin/command" "-dosomething")  ## Quoting is not necessary sometimes. Just a demo.
MY_ARGUMENTS=("fubar")  ## You can add more.

"${MY_COMMAND[@]}" "${MY_ARGUMENTS[@]}"  ## Execute.
```