# Concatenate command string in a shell script in Google Colab

Tags: python, shell, google-colaboratory

Suppose we have a string variable in python and we want to concatenate it with other string in the shell script. For example, suppose the variable is a base address. We want to run a command, `rm` for example, over a file in the base directory, like the following:

```
base_address = "<addr>"
!echo "${base_address}/file_name.xml"
```

But it doesn't work, here (in contrast to the [bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18596857/concatenate-command-string-in-a-shell-script)). It's the same story for `"$base_address/file_name.xml"`. What is the solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To contact a string variable in the shell script, you need to put it besides the other part of the string like the following:

```
base_address = "<addr>"
!echo $base_address"/file_name.xml"
```

Moreover, if you have a variable for the file name you can do it quite similar:

```
base_address = "<addr>/"
file_name = "file_name.xml"
!echo $base_address$file_name
```